# Is it possible to start a zookeeper server instance in process, say for unit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-zookeeper

Calling org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main() isn't working.

Comment: Also, the curator framework ships with a in memory zookeeper implementation for use in unit tests

Comment: curator does ship with a testing zookeeper, but it is _not_ in memory.  it stores data on disk, in a temp directory.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

To start `ZooKeeper` you have to execute `ZooKeeperServerMain` class.

You can use following code to start `ZooKeeper` in embedded mode.

```
Properties startupProperties = ...

QuorumPeerConfig quorumConfiguration = new QuorumPeerConfig();
try {
    quorumConfiguration.parseProperties(startupProperties);
} catch(Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

zooKeeperServer = new ZooKeeperServerMain();
final ServerConfig configuration = new ServerConfig();
configuration.readFrom(quorumConfiguration);

new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            zooKeeperServer.runFromConfig(configuration);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("ZooKeeper Failed", e);
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: This is the way to go for unit tests.   Using QuorumPeerMain is only for Multi Server (Clustered) Zookeeper.

Comment: This is useful in the context of BeforeClass, but shutting this down between tests (to clean out the nodes, for example) is non-trivial -- I gave up and switched to a Curator-based solution. (thread.stop/interrupt in After would stop the JUnitRunner)

Comment: Any chance you know how to set this up in a C++ project?

Comment: serup, Zookeeper is a Java process

Comment: Hi, can you give an example of startup properties to set?

Answer (score 60):

Netfix opensourced [Curator](https://curator.incubator.apache.org/curator-framework/index.html) a framework to make use of Zookeeper even more convenient. It has build in test server class. Just add this *test* dependency to your project descriptor be it maven, gradle or else:

```
org.apache.curator:curator-framework:4.0.1
org.apache.curator:curator-test:4.0.1
```

And here are the test essentials.

```
TestingServer zkTestServer;
CuratorFramework cli;

@Before
public void startZookeeper() throws Exception {
    zkTestServer = new TestingServer(2181);
    cli = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(zkTestServer.getConnectString(), new RetryOneTime(2000));
    cli.start();
}

@After
public void stopZookeeper() throws IOException {
    cli.close();
    zkTestServer.stop();
}
```

With `cli` creating any test data is very easy (requires the `curator-framework` dependency).

```
cli.create()
   .creatingParentsIfNeeded()
   .forPath("/a1", "testvalue".getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: For me it didn't work without cli.start() using Curator version 2.10.0

Comment: @MichaelBöckling thanks! I also needed to call `cli.start()` first then it started working

Comment: Hi @gertas. Ahem, could Curator be used to monitor an ensemble of zookeepers, and if 1 of the zookeeper instance went down, could it be used to restart it automatically?

Answer (score 12):

You can use something like this.

```
int clientPort = 21818; // none-standard
int numConnections = 5000;
int tickTime = 2000;
String dataDirectory = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");

File dir = new File(dataDirectory, "zookeeper").getAbsoluteFile();

ZooKeeperServer server = new ZooKeeperServer(dir, dir, tickTime);
NIOServerCnxn.Factory standaloneServerFactory = new NIOServerCnxn.Factory(new InetSocketAddress(clientPort), numConnections);

standaloneServerFactory.startup(server); // start the server.
```

And to shut it down just call `standaloneServerFactory.shutdown()`

Answer (score 4):

Building on [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9286349/121324)'s answer by adding the use of an ephemeral port (shown by `zkPort`) and updated for latest ZK API:

```
int tickTime = 2000;
int numConnections = 5000;
String dataDirectory = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");

File dir = new File(dataDirectory, "zookeeper").getAbsoluteFile();

ZooKeeperServer server = new ZooKeeperServer(dir, dir, tickTime);
standaloneServerFactory = ServerCnxnFactory.createFactory(0, numConnections);
int zkPort = standaloneServerFactory.getLocalPort();

standaloneServerFactory.startup(server);
```

Comment: You probably can't start zoo keeper server this way as it will block all subsequent code from executing after standaloneServerFactory.startup(server);

Answer (score 2):

```
ServerConfig config = new ServerConfig();
config.parse(new String[] {port, dir});
ZooKeeperServerMain zk = new ZooKeeperServerMain();
zk.runFromConfig(config);
```

Comment: You can't run zookeeper server this way as it will block the following code i.e. code after zk.runFromConfig(config); from getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

An updated version of GeoffBourne's answer.

```
    int clientPort = 2199; // not standard
    int numConnections = 5000;
    int tickTime = 2000;
    String dataDirectory = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");

    File dir = new File(dataDirectory, "zookeeper").getAbsoluteFile();

    ZooKeeperServer server = new ZooKeeperServer(dir, dir, tickTime);
    ServerCnxnFactory factory = new NIOServerCnxnFactory();
    factory.configure(new InetSocketAddress(clientPort), numConnections);

    factory.startup(server); // start the server.

    // ...shutdown some time later
    factory.shutdown();
```