# Is it possible to start an embedded zookeeper server instance for unit testing in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, apache-zookeeper, kazoo

I'd like to create and destroy a zookeeper server when unit-testing as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286054/is-it-possible-to-start-a-zookeeper-server-instance-in-process-say-for-unit-tes) question.
Is it possible to create an embedded in-memory server for example with [kazoo](/questions/tagged/kazoo)?